# Need help in deriving components of forces when they depend on lengths and angles. (2 questions)

Tags: statics

I am having difficulty with two questions from a book I am studying about statics. I have seen the answers but it did not help me understand how the answers are derived. I want some advice on how to think about these types of problems and whether there are any tricks which help to solve them.

Question 1 (1st image);

A small probe is gently forced against a circular surface with a vertical force F (the red vector). Determine the n- and t-components of this force as functions of the horizontal position S.

[image]

Question 2 (2nd image);

Determine the x- and y-components of the tension T which is applied to point A of the bar OA. Neglect the effects of  the small pulley at B. Assume that R and alpha are known.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, these are just geometry problems.

**The answer to the first question:**

$$\begin{align}
F_n &= F\dfrac{(r^2 - s^2)^(1/2)}{r} \\
F_t &= F\dfrac{s}{r}
\end{align}$$

Figure shows the details of the solution.

[image: Solution of the first question]

If you think that way, you can solve the second question.